# Debugging release version of Android app

Tags: android

I have an app that works fine in debug mode, but when I create a signed apk and install it on the same phone, some features do not work.

Is there a way to get console messages from the release version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please specify the feature which is not working in signed apk.

Comment: you have used pro-guard to generate signed APK?? post error logs

Answer (score 0):

@Matt If it is working fine in your simulator while running in debug mode then obviously it should work with your apk in mobile device as well. Actually elaborate your question.

Comment: I am doing an HTTP  post against my server on Azure. In debug it works fine, In release, it does not go through. I am checking the server end and there is no response at all. In debug mode, I am getting a response.

Comment: @Matt Can you please post your code. As per my understanding you have make the API to call from client to server and in debug mode you are getting response but while installing apk in mobile device you are not getting any response from server. Is my understanding is correct? Could you please share your code so that it will be easy to fix the bug for us.

Answer (score 0):

In you release gradle build change to this

```
  release {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
```

hope this is helpful .